# Create 3D array from existing 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dimensions

I am trying to create an array that is with dimensions:

```
a(Days,Hours,Station)
```

I have hourly data for array 'a' for 2 stations over 61 days so currently I have this array with these dimensions:

```
a(1464,2)
```

Where the 1464 is the number of hourly data points per station that I have (24 hours*61 days). However I want to break it down even further and add another dimension that has Days so the dimensions would then be:

```
a(61 days,24 hours/day, 2 stations)
```

Any ideas on how I would correctly be able to take the array 'a' that I currently have and change it into these 3 dimensions?

Comment: a is numpy array or standard array?

Comment: a is a numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split array `a` to chunks with maximum length `size`.

```
def chunks( a, size ):
    arr = iter( a )
    for v in arr:
        tmp = [ v ]
        for i,v in zip( range( size - 1 ), arr ):
            tmp.append( v )

        yield tmp

splitted = list( chunks( a, 24 ) )
```

Comment: Oh ok interesting. I suppose I could do this then. I also read about np.rearrage(a, (61,2,2)) so I tried that but I don't exactly know what the function is doing behind the scenes. Are you familiar with this? Would this be an easy solution too?

Comment: Also this doesn't quite work. Splitted is of dimensions (1,2,1464) instead of (61,24,2) like I want.

Comment: Can't find any info on np.rearrage. Don't know anything abount it.

Comment: Is it possible that shape of `a` is (2, 1464)? It's only possible reason, that i can find, that would lead to (1, 2, 1646).?

Comment: Yes that is why! So I need to switch the dimensions around somehow and then if I do that and use this code it works. Thanks! Meghan

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a 61x24x2 array. This should work:

```
b = []
for i in xrange(61):
    b.append(a[i*61:(i+1)*61])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're first field is *hours * days*, a transformation would simply be:
a(x, y) => a(x // 24, x % 24, y)

`x // 24` is floor division so `1500 // 24 = 62`, the days. You did not specify, but I assume the "Hours" field would be the remaining hours; so `x % 24` gets the remaining hours, and `1500 % 25 = 12`, the number of hours. Lastly, the station field remains the same.

I don't think you can modify the structure of a list/array in Python, so you would need to create a new one. I'm also not sure if you're actually using the built-in *list* or the *array*. I'm not too familiar with the *array* class so this isn't a complete answer, but I hope it points you in the right direction arithmetically.